# Maven is picking up the oldest snapshot in Archiva - why?

Tags: maven, archiva

I have a projectA-parent with the following structure:

```
projectA-parent|
----------------|projectA
----------------|projectA-core
----------------|projectA-api
```

The module projectA simply defines dependencies to core and api [1], so I can just define a dependency to projectA in other projects that need both the core and the api. I deploy the project to Archiva (1.4-M2), to a SNAPSHOT repository.

I have another project X where I define a dependency to projectA, and this afternoon the goal "mvn compile" started failing with unresolved compilation issues. Upon investigation with "mvn dependency:tree" on that project I discovered that, under projectA, the dependency to projectA-core was declared as "runtime". While this morning it was like this, I performed several mvn installs since where the scope is "compile" (see [1], where the most recent pom definition is listed).

Looking at archiva, I see the following files for this project (abbreviated):

```
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.084920-61-tests.jar
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.084920-61-tests.jar.md5
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.084920-61-tests.jar.sha1
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.084920-61.jar
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.084920-61.jar.md5
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.084920-61.jar.sha1
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.084920-61.pom
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.084920-61.pom.md5
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.084920-61.pom.sha1
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.172412-87-tests.jar
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.172412-87-tests.jar.md5
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.172412-87-tests.jar.sha1
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.172412-87.pom
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.172412-87.pom.md5
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.172412-87.pom.sha1
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.180733-90.pom
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.180733-90.pom.md5
projectA-0.0.7-20120712.180733-90.pom.sha1
```

Here's the interesting part: if I delete projectA from my local .m2/repository, even if I "mvn compile -U" **I will get th 08:49 version, not the 18:07 one!** This means **either maven or archiva** are resolving the 1st sNAPSHOT of the day and not the most recent one. 
**Why is that, and how can one solve this?**

[1]:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.projectA</groupId>
            <artifactId>projectA-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.projectA</groupId>
            <artifactId>projectA-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the *packaging* of your projectA ('`jar`' or '`pom`'). It only exists a '`jar`' artefact for 08:49.

I suppose you changed the packaging to '`pom`'. Thus if you declare the library as dependency in other projects you have to set `<type>pom</type>`.

Comment: Oh wow, now I feel embarassed. You're absolutely right. I'd forgotten to change the dependency type in X to type pom!